# Scala recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion

```
object MainObject {  
   def main(args: Array[String]) {  
        var result = recur(15,2)  
        print(result)  
    }  
    def recur(a:Int,b:Int):Int={
        if(b==0)
        0
        else
        a+recur(a,b-1)
    }
}
```

in this above code, can somebody explain to me how step by step this gets executed?

Please correct me if I am wrong: after else there is recur function does this call `recur(15,2)` in each iteration? By deducting on each time? If yes then at 3rd run `b` will be 0, so why it doesn't return 0 as that if becomes true.

Comment: Naveen, if one of the solutions below solves the problem/question for you, can you please indicate this by checking the corresponding green checkmark?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of comments.

1) Since the value of result is only assigned once it would be more idiomatic, and generally preferable to use `val` instead of `var`.

[val vs var in Scala](https://sanaulla.info/2009/07/02/val-versus-var-in-scala-2/)

2) Also, in Scala you can define functions inside functions, this is often useful when you don't want to expose the behavior of the recursion to the larger context.

3) Consider outside-in evaluation:

1. `recur(15, 2)` returns `15 + recur(15, 1)`
2. `recur(15, 1)` returns `15 + recur(15, 0)`
3. `recur(15, 0)` returns `0`

Now substitute:

1. `recur(15, 1)` returns `15 + 0`
2. `recur(15, 2)` returns  `15 + 15` or `30`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to visualize this, IMHO, is to follow the execution "from the outside in":

1. First, we call `recur(15, 2)`, which will return `15 + recur(15, 1)`
2. Now, let's evaluate `recur(15, 1)` - it will return `15 + recur(15, 0)`.
3. Now, we should evaluate `recur(15, 0)`, which, as you mentioned, will return `0`.
4. If so, the result of step 2 is `15+0`, or `15`.
5. If so, the result of step 1 is `15+15`, or `30`.

Comment: I think in step four you mean "the result of step 2 is 15 + 0" since `recur(15,0)` returns zero as you rightly claim. The answer I am reasonably sure should be 30 not 45.

Comment: @AhmadRagab yup, momentary lapse of concentration on my part, edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to look at this one is to ascribe values to each stage of the calculation, and calculate is backwards:

```
For each step, the second parameter is reduced by 1 and the first stays the same.
At b = 0, the output is 0.
recur(15, 2) = 15 + recur(15, 1)
recur(15, 1) = 15 + recur(15, 0)
recur(15, 0) = 0

We know that recur(15, 0) = 0
recur(15, 1) == 15 + recur(15, 0) == 15 + 0 == 15

And because recur(15, 1) = 15
recur(15, 2) == 15 + recur(15, 1) == 15 + 15 == 30
```

So the answer to `recur(15, 2)` is 30. Going backwards like this is very helpful for simpler functions but can get very complex so writing it out like I have or jotting down the output at each stage so you don't lose track of your calculations.

... or get a compiler to do it. Either works.